# Passing mapped button ID to component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have react mapping that maps an array of objects into their own `<cards />`. Each card has its own button that opens up a `<dialog />`. I am trying to pass the unique ID from each object through to the relevant dialog component. At the moment I am getting all IDs through to the `<dialog />` no matter which dialog is open.

Each dialog based on the ID will call unique data, currently I am getting all which I do not want.

```
            {vehicles !== undefined ? vehicles.map(model => (
                <React.Fragment>
                        <Card>
                            <CardActions className={classes.cardActions}>
                                <Button fullWidth color="#333" onClick={this.handleDialog}>
                                    FIND OUT MORE
                            </Button>
                            </CardActions>
                        </Card>

                    <VehicleDialog
                        key={model.id}
                        onClose={this.handleDialog}
                        open={this.state.open}
                        id={model.id} //passes all IDs to this component
                    />
                </React.Fragment>
            ))
                :
                null
            }
```

My handle is standard:

```
handleDialog = () => {
    this.setState({ open: !this.state.open });
};
```

I have looked into solutions where you pass the ID with the onClick, just not sure how to then pass that one through to the component. Maybe there is a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually what is happening here is, you are rendering multiple `VehicleDialog` in a loop. What you should do is- take the `VehicleDialog` out of the loop (out of the `map`, I mean). And render it after the mapping. Now when a button is clicked take note (in your `state`) of which `model.id` wants to open the `VehicleDialog`.

So let's first modify your handler to take an model's `id` as argument. It returns a function that sets the `state.open` and `state.modelId`. So whenever your dialog is open, it knows which model id wanted to open it (from state.modelId).

```
handleDialog = (id) => () => {
    this.setState({ 
        open: !this.state.open,
        modelId: id
    });
};
```

Now let's cut the dialog out of the loop and modify the `onClick` props of the buttons to reflect the new handler design change. After the loop, render a single dialog:

```
{vehicles !== undefined ? vehicles.map(model => (
    <Card>
        <CardActions className={classes.cardActions}>
            <Button fullWidth color="#333" onClick={this.handleDialog(model.id)}>
                FIND OUT MORE
            </Button>
        </CardActions>
    </Card>
)):null
}

<VehicleDialog
    key={model.id}
    onClose={this.handleDialog}
    open={this.state.open}
    id={this.state.modelId}
/>
```